# How to handle routing in MEAN application for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I want to access my admin end using the URL `http://localhost:3000/users/123` for which I have the following routing using Angular UI-Router module:

```
.state('users', {
    url: '/users/:id',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/admin/index.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        },
        'sidebar@users': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/admin/sidebar.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        },
        'content@users': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/admin/content.html',
            controller: 'UserController'
        },
        //other named views
    }

})
```

Accessing `http://localhost:3000/users/123` gives me 404 error through NodeJS.

At the same time I could access the `http://localhost:3000/questions/342359` URL through `<a ui-sref="questions({ id: {{qid}} })">Ask</a>` in the front end with the following configuration:

```
.state('questions', {
    url: '/questions/:id',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'partials/questions.html',
            controller: 'QuestionController'
        },
        //other named views
    }
})
```

Following is the `express.Router()` for the front end and the admin end:

```
/* GET front end */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Front' });
});

/* GET admin end */
router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.render('users', { title: 'Admin' });
});
```

Both `index.ejs` and `users.ejs` have the `<div ui-view></div>` in them. The `<div ui-view></div>` in `index.ejs` takes `partials/index.html` in it and the `<div ui-view></div>` in `users.ejs` takes `partials/admin/index.html` in it. Both the `partials/index.html` and the `partials/admin/index.html` have some named views in them.

Its like I have 2 pages in my application (front end and admin end) and both the pages I want to behave like single page app, for which I have partials for each of the end(front end and admin end).

Could somebody help understand that how could I access `partials/admin/index.html` without getting the `404` error?

**Edit**: **Some More Code**

**index.ejs (Front end)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%title%></title>
    <!-- CSS files for front end to make front end look pretty -->
</head>
<body>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <!-- JavaScript files for front end to make front end look pretty and other Angular specific stuff -->
</body>
</html>
```

**/partials/index.html (Front end)**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row margin-bottom-40">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="content-page">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div ui-view="foo"></div>
                        <div ui-view="bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**users.ejs (Admin end)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%title%></title>
    <!-- CSS files for admin end to make amdin end look pretty -->
</head>
<body>

<div ui-view></div>

<!-- JavaScript files for admin end to make admin end look pretty and other Angular specific stuff -->
</body>
</html>
```

**/partials/admin/index.html (Admin end)**

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue seems to be very hardly examined without some working example... do you have some plunker? I would suggest create a draft of your goal (simplified), without server part, without html5. Make it running and then enhance it with next parts. If you create a plunker, you'd get more help here then - I'd say...

Comment: @RadimKöhler: I've edited the post and added some more code. The thing is that I get a 404 error when I access `http://localhost:3000/users/123` through this URL, but I could access it `<a ui-sref="users({ id: 123 })">User 123</a>`. I need to have the admin end look different for which I created `users.ejs` and put all the CSS and JavaScript files in it and used it as the base for the admin end. Similarly I created an `index.ejs` for the front end. But even if I could access User 123 using `<a ui-sref="users({ id: 123 })">User 123</a>` the admin view gets embedded inside the front end.

Comment: I would say, I do understand where is the issue. The single app approach is broken here - there is multi app approach. And this is confusing for server and client as well - because it is not clear which app belongs to which url. So - I would suggest. 1) Turn off the HTML5. 2) place each app on different url: like `http://localhost:3000/user.html` and `http://localhost:3000/admin.html`. That scenario should work ... no confusion anymore. Then you can start to think about it more. But I would stop your idea at all (if I could) - try to return to SPA, try to find a way there...

Comment: @RadimKöhler: Many thanks, am going to try to do it using SPA approach.

Comment: ;) wow.. you've surprised me. Nicely! ;) Really good decision. This way, you will gain more for sure. Firstly you will solve current issue - lately simplified maintenance, easier extending, more common features (shared run time caching among all views)... good luck, sir. Good decision, I'd say