# AngularJS directive ng-if at head and body elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Would it be valid html to have AngularJS `ng-if` directive at the html head and body elements like below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head ng-if="condition">
    <!-- if conditon is true -->
  </head>

  <head ng-if="condition">
    <!-- if condition is false -->
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-if="condition">
    <!-- if conditon is true -->
  </body>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-if="condition">
    <!-- if conditon is false-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Would it work?

Comment: Simply give it a try :) . Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags.

Comment: I dont see any problem with it

Comment: Blackhole and Sridhar: Why am I getting both the `body` elements here http://plnkr.co/edit/mj1kXh20G6fwiPzzXG2V ?

Comment: what is your use case? Where were you planning on putting scripts? Keep in mind that the browser has to process the basic html before scripts fire, so browser will see 2 heads and 2 body's

Comment: @charlietfl: I want to have different looks for front end and admin end of my app. I want the app to be single page, so based on the named views using `angular-ui-router` module I want to use CSS and JavaScript accordingly.

Comment: stop and think about browser process loading a page. You can't put 2 heads. Angular won't compile in the sequence you are hoping for and browser has no idea what ng-if is

Comment: Hi skip this question is better.  If it is going to be one single page application it needs to share the js the stylesheets can be manually/dynamically loaded using js.

Comment: @charlietfl: How could I then have different look and feel for front end and the admin end as I would need different CSS and JavaScript files for that? Is it possible to be done?

Comment: @shaunhusain: How could I dynamically load style-sheets based on a condition?

Comment: do you really need admin and front end in one page? From security point of view it makes very little sense. If you want to share code beteen them, create modules you can inject in both

Comment: @charlietfl: Actually I started with two different pages. `index.ejs` and `users.ejs`. I explained the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830823/how-to-handle-routing-in-mean-application-for-multiple-pages where I was advised not take the SPA approach.

Comment: @charlietfl: I just need to have different looks for front end and admin end. And I want them both to work like SPA and both of those pages should be part of the same angular application. How could I achieve that?

Comment: 2 different outputs , really not hard. Use server side includes to manage what iniital resources go into each page

Comment: @charlietfl: Could you suggest me any resources on it. I am just quite new to the MEAN world.

Comment: you are basically building 2 different applications. I think you are overcomplicating that fact

Comment: Yeah agree with charlietfl here you're really better off having these be two separate sites, they can have some common modules that you can include by making those into bower components or by using git submodules (I've gone the former route).  There can be one Mongo/Express/Node part that handles the API for both and deals with authentication and resource management but if they will be mostly different on the front end you might as well just make two separate SPAs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example directive to load up a CSS file dynamically though unloading one is another issue really since you need to keep track of which script/style tag was added and remove the appropriate one:

http://plnkr.co/edit/5fCUV6WDxoLZ8kk9NSxb?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).directive("styleSheetLoader", function(){
  function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
   if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
   }
   else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
    var fileref=document.createElement("link")
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
   }
   if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
  }
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope: {condition:"@", cssFile:"@"},
    link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
      console.log(iAttrs.condition);
      if(iAttrs.condition)
      {
        console.log("here", iAttrs.cssFile)
        loadjscssfile(iAttrs.cssFile, "css");
      }
      iAttrs.$observe("condition", function(){

        if(iAttrs.condition)
        {
          console.log("here", iAttrs.cssFile)
          loadjscssfile(iAttrs.cssFile, "css");
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Used a function referenced from here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

**Edit** added some parts in the plunkr to remove the other stylesheets that were added with a factory I made before adding a new one on, it's not perfect but it works.